# Retain the Office App Custom Tab across multiple office sessions

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have a office app that creates a custom tab defined in the office addin manifest and uses office js technology. when i sideload  the addin in windows or MAC , and inserts the addin , the custom tab appears. But when i close the office process and restarts the office process , the custom tab is not persisted. Again i have to go to insert/MyAddins and select myaddin to bring back the custom tab again. Any idea how to persist the tab across multiple office sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Centralized Deployment to deploy your add-in, either to yourself or a team of people. This will persist across sessions and will work across Online, Mac, and Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment

To do this, you will need IT admin rights. One easy way to get access is by using your own or a separate Office 365 subscription for development.  You can get one for free with the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://aka.ms/o365devprogram).

Note: Centralized Deployment of the manifest typically works better for things that are in production. If you are working on a feature that requires a manifest change that is in preview, then you may still need to follow the previous sideload approach.